# Serverless monorepo in nestjs how to use and package shared utils in a monorepo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, nestjs, serverless

I have a monorepo I'm trying to build up to develop and deploy lambdas in nestjs, I'm having alot of problem's with my shared utils that I want to share between my lambdas. Currently I'm using serverless-plugin-include-dependencies so I can store all my dependencies in one node_modules at the root, and it grabs the necessary utils, and brings them into a node_module when packaged. However I am unable to get shared utils to work. I'm not sure what the best way is to go about it.

I'm using yarn and yarn workspaces, additionally i'm using serverless. I have all these in my serverless.yml

```
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-monorepo
  - serverless-plugin-common-excludes
  - serverless-plugin-include-dependencies
  - serverless-offline
```

Unsure if the monorepo one is actually properly being used.

```
/my-project
|-- /node_modules
|-- /apps
|   |-- /lambda
|   |   |-- /src
|   |   |-- /dist
|   |   |-- package.json
|   |   |-- serverless.yml
|   |   |-- tsconfig.json
|   |   |-- tsconfig.build.json
|   |   |-- nest-cli.json
|   |-- /another-lambda
|   |   |-- /src
|   |   |-- /dist
|   |   |-- package.json
|   |   |-- serverless.yml
|   |   |-- tsconfig.json
|   |   |-- tsconfig.build.json
|   |   |-- nest-cli.json
|   |-- # ... more lambdas
|-- /utils
|   |-- /mysql-utils
|   |   |-- /src
|   |   |-- /dist
|   |   |-- package.json
|   |   |-- tsconfig.json
|   |   |-- tsconfig.build.json
|   |-- # ... more utils
|-- package.json
|-- yarn.lock
|-- tsconfig.json
|-- .gitignore
|-- serverless.yml
```

I am building this repo to work on it with a team, and it's easier to test using serverless offline, so I want to code to work both locally and be able to be deployed to aws via serverless deploy.

I started off by trying to use layers, I had issues with the routing that aws needs (throught opt) vs the actual route for local testing. Additionally unless I read incorrectly it looks like you can only have 5 layers for each serverless.yml file, which could down the line not be enough. I struggled to find a good way to create the layers in nestjs and deploy from serverless like the lambdas, and couldn't find good documentation.

So I tried to just point directly to it and match the structures up, however when packaged it just didn't seem logical or possible to get that to work.

I moved on to requiring the util as a dependency for my lambda package.json,

```
"dependencies": {
    "mysql-utils": "file:../../utils/mysql-utils"
  },
```

which works except it creates a node_module of the dependencies for the util and a copy of entire specific util directory in node_module in my lambda. Which wouldnt be the worst except, I'm going to have quite a few lambdas for this project, and that will be duplicating code over and over again which is a waste of space and seems very inefficient. It's also copying over the entire directory

```
|   |-- /mysql-utils
|   |   |-- /src
|   |   |-- /dist
|   |   |-- package.json
|   |   |-- tsconfig.json
|   |   |-- tsconfig.build.json
```

Which I definitely don't need the tsconfigs and the src folder, maybe the package? Im not sure.

I need a better long term dynamic solution for this.

I would be okay if the code duplicated once in my root node_modules, however if we could avoid duplications all together that would be best. But all in all I am up for a better solution, if there is one..